# Is it possible to use Catel with EntityFramework 7?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, catel

I'm using the pre-release EF7 because it provides Microsoft support for SQLite (a requirement).  I was hoping to use some of the Catel.Extensions.EntityFramework features in my development, but it looks like Catel only supports EF5 and EF6.

Is there a way to get Catel.Extensions.EntityFramework6 to work with EF7?  My (possibly naïve) assumption is EF7 is mostly backwards compatible with EF6.  And I probably don't know how packages really work.

Or, is there a pre-release of Catel.Extensions.EntityFramework that works with EF7?

If you have any questions or need more info, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not supported yet since it's still in beta. There is a branch, but it's a bit outdates. But you are free to create a PR :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Yes, I expected not a lot of work has gone into Catel EF7 support until it gets closer to a stable release, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geert -- I'll copy your response as the answer.

*It's not supported yet since it's still in beta. There is a branch, but it's a bit outdates. But you are free to create a PR :-) – Geert van Horrik Feb 12 at 18:06*